# Why I don´t need to use static in my constructor method?

Tags: java, oop

I´m creating a class in Java with a static method called addCustomer which returns an instance of this class for me, like so:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer {
    private ArrayList<Double> transactions;
    private String name;
        
    public static Customer addCustomer(String name, Double transaction){
        this.name = name;
        return new Customer();
    }
}
```

And it gives me an error in the first line of the addCustomer method

```
this.name = name;
```

because I can´t use a non-static variable in a static method, which makes totally sense for me. But then I tried to create a private constructor(with the name and transactions values) for the same class and use it instead of Customer() in my addCustomer method.
Like this:

```
    private Customer(String name, Double transaction){
        this.name = name;
        transactions = new ArrayList<Double>();
        transactions.add(transaction);
    }
    
    public static Customer addCustomer(String name, Double transaction){
        return new Customer(name,transaction);
    }
```

I thought I had to put static modifier in the constructor because of the static method addCustomer(), but my IDE says it´s not allowed in the constructor. And, which doesn´t make any sense for me, I can use the addCustomer() method like this (without an static in constructor), so why can I still use it even though it´s not a static method and the variables inside it are not as well?

Comment: It's because you use your constructor with the `new` construct. That is something completely different than calling a method.

Comment: ther's no `this` in a static method

Comment: Instance methods, you call on an instance. Static methods, you call on a class. Constructors are called on a new instance when you use the `new` operator. They're not the same as methods.

Comment: Constructors are special. You don't need an existing instance to call them (which makes them feel static) but they have access to a `this` reference (which makes them feel non-static). Best to think of them as their own thing that is different from all other methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer {
    private ArrayList<Double> transactions;
    private String name;

    public Customer(String name, Double transaction) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

To get a `Customer` type, you would just do `Customer customer = new Customer(<name>, <transaction>)`. If you want to be able to call `Customer.addCustomer(<name>, <transaction>)` like shown above, you could use:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer {
    private ArrayList<Double> transactions;
    private String name;

    public Customer(String name, Double transaction) {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public static Customer addCustomer(String name, Double transaction) {
        return new Customer(name, transaction);
    }
}
```

The constructor method needs to be the same name (case sensitive) as the class. It also needs to be `public ClassName`, without the usual return value.